# AWS Route53 record creation "DomainLabelTooLong" Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

While creating the new record with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl` as my subdomain I'm getting the below error.

```
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: DomainLabelTooLong (Domain label is too long) encountered with 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl')
```

From [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html#:%7E:text=The%20total%20length%20of%20a%20domain%20name%20cannot%20exceed%20255%20bytes%2C%20including%20the%20dots)  i found the below statement.

> The total length of a domain name cannot exceed 255 bytes, including the dots.

FYI my root domain length is 20 , 20+ 64 (subdomain) also not exceeds this 255 bytes.

Anyone got the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with the total length of your domain name, but the length of your subdomain. From the same [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html):

> Domain names (including the names of domains, hosted zones, and records) consist of a series of labels separated by dots. Each label can be up to 63 bytes long.

In this case, your subdomain name `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl` is one such label. It's 64 characters long and therefore exceeds the 63 byte limit.